# More complex features in machine learning : Titanic dataset

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I'm delving into "machine learning". In particular, I'm looking at the titanic dataset. Let's assume we can identify families by surname...

I would have thought, one of the best predictors where one has "parch" or "sibsp", i.e. family members would be the "family outcome". If one imagines a heirachy father -> mother -> siblings then I suspect a good predictor might be that the surivial outcome is not lower than the outcome of the highest member in the heirachy.

i.e. if dad survived, mum and siblings did. If mum survived, siblings probably okay, dad might not. siblings are more likely to survive together.

I've done some light reading on the internet. I'm out of my depth, and can't find anything super obvious to me... to see what I mean, the raw data steps would be something like

```matlab
spouses = data(data.SibSp >= 1, :);
spouseNames = split(string(data.Name), ",");
sort(spouseNames)
```

Is such a thing expressible in machine learning techniques? Can someone give me a pointer on how? Is this somehow equivalent to including the "surname", "Age" and gender fields in a KNN algorithm?

Will "the machine" figure all this out alone?

Comment: Can anyone explain why this is downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the categorical variables, in your case it's going to add a plenty of columns on your data set each one of them representing the surname of a person, if someone is a member of the family will be labeled as 1 otherwise will be 0.